# Noun opposite of complex, intricate

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

So something that is like "straightforwardness". I remember using it in essays years ago but now it's completely out of my mind and it's driving me crazy! The sentence I want to use it in is as follows: 
"Error handling was kept to a minimum as straightforwardness was given priority".

So its a word that means "keeping things simple" as a noun.

Comment: Simply _simplicity_?

Comment: "elegance", in the engineering sense?  Defns C & D here: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elegance

Comment: Evidentness, obviousness, simplicity, triviality?

Comment: For the sake of **clarity** when showing the main purpose of the code, a programming example might leave out error-handling.

Comment: Error handling was kept to a minimum as I wanted **clean code**.

Answer (score 1):

Since the topic is code, I'd suggest efficiency, readability, or brevity, along with the previously mentioned clarity and simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on who your audience is.

If it's meant for software developers:

> Error handling **code** was kept to a minimum by following the KISS principle.

<sup>I've added "code" since you're not saying simplicity reduces the actual number of errors.</sup>

If it's meant for managers who have political science degrees:

> Error handling **code** was kept to a minimum following best practices that encourage simplicity.